# How can I remove all QTranslator from the app?

Tags: qt, qtranslator

I want to change the language using `QCoreApplication::installTranslator` with a few different `.qm` files for every language (different parts of the project result in different .qm files).

It is fine to use more than one .qm file :

> [QCoreApplication::installTranslator(QTranslator *translationFile)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#installTranslator)
>   Multiple translation files can be installed. Translations are searched
>   for in the reverse order in which they were installed, so the most
>   recently installed translation file is searched first and the first
>   translation file installed is searched last.

But, if I do not [remove](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#removeTranslator) the older translators, they are still candidates for translations. Even though they would be the less recently installed translators.

How can I clear any file loaded previously before loading the wanted ones ?

The only way I see is to keep the pointers I installed and remove them one by one when I want to change, but is there something more straightforward ?

Comment: You can show the code that you comment to understand better.

Comment: Just maintain some list of old translators. Or use some common parent (it can be some dummy `QObject`) to maintain it. In such case you will be able to remove respective translations. I don't see it should be a problem.

Comment: @MarekR it is not, but it would be convenient to have the QApp doing it, because it already knows the translators you installed, it could just clear its private list of translators instead of having me to remove them one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maintain a list of the installed translators :

```
// Install the translators
for (auto fileName : qAsConst(fileList)) {
    auto translator = QSharedPointer<QTranslator>::create();
    translator->load(fileName);

    m_currentTranslators << translator;
    QCoreApplication::installTranslator(translator.data());
}
```

And to remove them all :

```
for (auto translator : qAsConst(m_currentTranslators)) {
    QCoreApplication::removeTranslator(translator.data());
}
m_currentTranslators.clear();
```